# Does AngularJS have a syntax to alias a property within a div?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, alias

This is kind of a weird question, but here's the idea:

Let's say I have a complex JSON object coming back from an HTTP call and attaching to the `$scope`. Something like this:

```
$scope.obj = {
    user: {
        id: 10,
        name: { first: 'Joe', last: 'Smith' },
        contact: {
            home: {
                street: '101 First St.',
                city: 'Myville',
                state: 'Jokelahoma',
                zip: '98765'
            },
            email: 'joeshmoe@gmail.com',
            phone: '+12345678901'
        }
    },
    purchase_hist: [
        { item_id: 11004, date: 'Thu, 06 Aug 2015 13:51:17 GMT' },
        { item_id: 97020, date: 'Fri, 31 Jul 2015 18:57:57 GMT' }
    ]
}
```

Now, if I wanted to display an overview of purchase history in an AngularJS partial, I could do something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="p in obj.purchase_hist">
        <td>{{p.item_id}}</td>
        <td>{{p.date}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The really convenient thing about this format (though it's not super evident here with so few props) is that the purchase being described is aliased as `p`. I don't have to do `obj.purchase_hist[0].item_id`, I can just do `p.item_id`.

But what about when I go to show the user's home address? Do I really have to do this?:

```
<div>
    <p>{{obj.user.contact.home.street}}</p>
    <p>{{obj.user.contact.home.city}}</p>
    <p>{{obj.user.contact.home.state}}</p>
    <p>{{obj.user.contact.home.zip}}</p>
</div>
```

That's really verbose. I would much rather use something akin to the `controller as ...` syntax, something like this:

```
<div ng-alias="obj.user.contact.home as uhome">
    <p>{{uhome.street}}</p>
    <p>{{uhome.city}}</p>
    <p>{{uhome.state}}</p>
    <p>{{uhome.zip}}</p>
</div>
```

Is there such a thing that exists in AngularJS ? Unfortunately I'm not very able to use plugins in my environment, so I'm specifically looking for a part of angular core that will work this way.

Thanks!

Comment: [ngInit](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.16/docs/api/ng/directive/ngInit)

Comment: Its really a nice question, you can copy your obj to other variable like : `$scope.p = obj.purchase_hist`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've written this little directive, which allow you to perform what you want :

**Directive ngAlias**

```
(function(){

  function ngAlias($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          var args = attrs.ngAlias.split('as').map(function(elm){return elm.replace(/ /g,'')});

          scope[args[0]] = '';

          var dot = args[1].split('.');

          var object = {};

          dot.forEach(function(value, index){
            index === 0
            ? object = scope[value]
            : object = object[value] === null ? object[value] = {} : object[value];
          });

          console.log(object)

          scope[args[0]] = object;
        }
    };
  }

angular
  .module('app')
  .directive('ngAlias', ngAlias);


})();
```

For example, set your object in your controller

**Controller**

```
(function(){

function Controller($scope) {


  $scope.obj = {
    toto: {
      nom: 'toto',
      prenom: 'tata'
    }
  };

}

angular
.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', Controller);

})();
```

And you can use it :

**HTML**

```
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

    <div ng-alias="toto as obj.toto">
      {{toto.nom}}
    </div>

  </body>
```

Comment: I think the ng-init is easier : ng-init="uhome = obj.user.contact.home" does the same as your directive, and is supposed to be used in this purpose.

Comment: Yeah clearly, i've just write this directive to answer the question "how to get same syntax as `controller as ...`", and for fun ^^.

Comment: ngInit half solves the problem, but it's a one-time eval. If I use `ng-init="uhome = obj.user.contact.home"` then the value of `obj.user.contact.home` changes after the view loads, there's no 2-way binding that will update the value of `uhome`. This directive will make that work.

Comment: Hey @PaulBoutes this is really awesome!  However, I did run into one issue where my obj.toto was null to begin with, and then it wouldn't update when it was set to "not null" later.  Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: @ClearCloud8 I've update the code, in order to handle null object. Now, the directive is able to update your null object.

Answer (score 6):

@PaulBoutes provided the answer I needed, and he should get the credit; I just wanted to add the version of the directive that I settled on based on his answer.

```
app.directive('alias', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var splits = attrs['alias'].trim().split(/\s+as\s+/);
            scope.$watch(splits[0], function(val) {
                scope.$eval(splits[1]+'=('+splits[0]+')');
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Same basic idea as Paul's, just cleaned up a little and made a little more flexible in terms of whitespace and such.

Usage example:

```
<div data-alias="obj.user.contact.home as uhome">
    <p>{{uhome.street}}</p>
    <p>{{uhome.city}}</p>
    <p>{{uhome.state}}</p>
    <p>{{uhome.zip}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Great. This will continually update unlike the answer by @PaulBoutes, well done

Comment: Code typo `scope.eval` should be `scope.$eval`.

Answer (score 4):

Certainly there's no shortage of workable solutions here, but there shouldn't be harm in adding another.

I threw this together the other day to save myself some typing and make my html easier to read. It creates a new child scope, so it doesn't pollute the existing scope with these aliases. It simply works by binding the parent scope's property to the new child scope with whatever name you specify.

```
app.directive('with', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            if (attrs.as) {
                scope[attrs.as] = scope.$eval(attrs.with);
            } else {
                angular.extend(scope, scope.$eval(attrs.with));
            }
        }
    };
});
```

So, instead of doing this:

```
<div>{{some.deeply.nested.model.id}} - {{some.deeply.nested.model.name}}</div>
```

Do this:

```
<div with="some.deeply.nested.model" as="t">{{t.id}} - {{t.name}}</div>
```

Or, do it without using `as`:

```
<div with="some.deeply.nested.model">{{id}} - {{name}}</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

I came across this just now and tested out the ngAlias directive, which may or may not work fine, I don't know because I had issues with it, probably due to some other unrelated error, and I decided on this simpler method:

```
<div ng-repeat="uhome in [obj.user.contact.home]">
    <p>{{uhome.street}}</p>
    <p>{{uhome.city}}</p>
    <p>{{uhome.state}}</p>
    <p>{{uhome.zip}}</p>
</div>
```

Tada!  "obj.user.contact.home" is now aliased to "uhome".  I believe this solution is actually exactly what you wanted when you asked this question, too, because it literally uses ng-repeat and therefore has all the benefits of ng-repeat's built-in aliasing mechanism.

Comment: Clever, and relatively clean! I like it

Comment: This should be the accepted anser. No custom directive needed and `ng-init` only works inside a `ng-repeat`, so this should be the goto.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-init="uhome = obj.user.contact.home">
  <p>{{uhome.street}}</p>
  <p>{{uhome.city}}</p>
  <p>{{uhome.state}}</p>
  <p>{{uhome.zip}}</p>
</div>
```

https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.16/docs/api/ng/directive/ngInit

Comment: I'm familiar with ng-init, but I don't like that it actually adds a property to the scope. Additionally, the ngInit docs page has this warning: "The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat. Besides this case, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope." Not that this means that I *couldn't* still use it, but it feels a little... dirty. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: In this case, there are 2 variables that are pointing to the same location, so it does not lower the perfs. A directive like ng-alias creates a brand new scope which is worse. They are telling ng-init is used to alias other properties, and I think that usually, no one does that.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know there is nothing really simple.
There are some hack. You can remap object to new scope using new controller

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl as c" ng-init="c.makeAlias(obj.user.contact.home)">
  <p>{{c.home}}</p>
</div>
```

where Ctrl just store `makeAlias` argument to it's scope as `home`

```
this.makeAlias(home) {
  this.home = home;
}
```

Another solution is use `$scope.$watch` and remap object to the more convenient one.

Comment: Your controller function should be named "makeHome", not "makeAlias". No matter what you pass to it, it will make it `home`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Angular provides out of box supports for such things. But You can definitely create Domain object.Convert your http response into domain object. Within your domain object you can have helper method to get the required information.
For example in your case you can have Domain object like this

```
  factory('User', function () {
    return function (id,name, contact, purchase_hist) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.contact = contact;
        this.purchase_hist = purchase_hist;
        this.getContact = function(){
          return this.contact.home;
        };

    };
})
```

you can use this domain object in your controller

```
$scope.user =  // domain object return  from your service
```

in html you can use

```
{{user.getContact().street}}
```

You can redefine your domain to make thing easier.It might be additional work. But when you have to do same thing again and again.One can enjoy writing code this way